# Gunicorn timeout not working

Tags: python, gunicorn

I am running a Gunicorn server with a Flask web app.  I use the following command to start the server

`gunicorn -c /config/serverConfig.py app:APP`

Inside `serverConfig.py`, I have `timeout = 180`

Howevever, the long running calls timeout after 120 seconds.

Is there something I should be doing differently?

Comment: Are there other settings in your config file that you can confirm are being applied? Also, maybe it should be `timeout = 180`.

Comment: Sorry, I meant `timeout = 180`.  No there isn't anything else in my code specifying 120.

Comment: Okay. I meant like `accesslog = '/file/path'`, to confirm that the gunicorn config file is being applied at all or if this is just a problem with timeout. Are you using this with nginx or another server? My other thought is that there's something else in your stack that has a timeout of 120, and that other thing is the real issue.

Comment: Glad to hear it's fixed!

Comment: @daniely you can add your own answer and accept it.  This is useful for others because it is easy to see at a glance that your problem is resolved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My app is running on a container group on the Bluemix cloud, and there is a 120s time out limit for the load balancer in front of the container.  This was overriding whatever timeout I had in my app.